# SQL Server 2014 SP3 DB emailer TLS 1.2 support

Tags: sql-server-2014, tls-1.2

I have SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4) 12.0.6329.1 running on Windows Server 2012R2 with .NET 3.5.30729.4926 installed

I can't get Database emailer to work with TLS 1.2

I tried everything in the article "TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server" to no avail.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

Can you advise please?

Comment: What error do you get, or how do you know it's not working?  Also, I generally like to run IIS Crypto (https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) on any server having a TLS issue just to make sure the TLS settings aren't messed up (that software is super handy if you don't use it already).

Comment: I check the email header and it shows: SMTP Server (version=TLS1_0, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA) where it should be SMTP  Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384). I got the second one working on the SQL2016 but no luck on 2014. I also used IISCrypto

Comment: Trying running IIS Crypto and let me know what results you have (the first screen just displays current SSL/TLS settings, ciphers, etc.).

Comment: Someone just provided me a fix on MSDN forum https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77d938f6-f15f-4727-9965-1c0d616d29dd/sql-server-2014-and-server-2012r2-database-mail-tls12?forum=sqlnetfx   SOLEVD :)

Answer (score 1):

This hotfix worked for me:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3154520/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework

emails from dbmailer are using TLS1.2 now